# Singles Entry return content

Tags: entries

I am brand new to Craft so excuse me if the question seems a little simple. Is this the best way to return the contents of a 'singles' section. Does everything end up in a for loop even if you are only returning a single entry.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('sectionHandle').limit(1).find() %}
  {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Also I am curious if 'entry' in the for loop actually means anything or is just a good symantic name to use for example could you say

```
{% for oranges in ...%}{% oranges.title %}{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a simple question, but a fundamental one.

Whenever you query one of Craft's Element API services (such as `craft.entries`, `craft.assets` and `craft.categories`) or a relational field (such as an Entries or Assets field, i.e. `entry.myAssetsField`) you'll get back an [ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) instance.

The ElementCriteriaModel is basically a fancy wrapper for your query, which you can call methods on (such as `.find()`, `.ids()`, `.first()` and `.last()`), in order to actually pull elements based on your criteria (e.g. `.section('sectionHandle')`). Some methods – such as `.find()` – will return an array of elements (Craft actually calls `.find()` implicitly unless you use [one of the other methods](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#fetching-the-elements)), while others will return a single element (`.first()`, `.last()`). There are also methods that can do different things entirely, such as returning an array of matching element IDs (`.ids()`).

In your example, you're using `.find()` – which means Craft will return an array of elements (even if there's only one). In such cases, it usually makes more sense to use `.first()`, to make Craft return a single element and avoid the `for` loop:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('sectionHandle').first() %}
```

However, since the query may not always return any matching elements, it's usually a good idea to wrap the result in a conditional:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('sectionHandle').first() %}
{% if entry %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

The above will of course also be true for any relational fields – consider an Assets field for a "featured image"; even if you limit the field to a single image, simply accessing the field in a template will always return an ElementCriteriaModel, unless you use `.first()`:

```
{# Returns an ElementCriteriaModel #}
{% set featuredImage = entry.someAssetsField %}

{# Returns an array of elements #}
{% set featuredImage = entry.someAssetsField.find() %}

{# Returns a single Asset #}
{% set featuredImage = entry.someAssetsField.first() %}
```

> Also I am curious if 'entry' in the for loop actually means anything or is just a good symantic name to use

It's just a semantic name – the result variable for your query can be named whatever you want:

```
{% set myAwesomeSingleEntry = craft.entries.section('sectionHandle').first() %}
```

However, a good thing to know about is that whenever Craft [matches the current URL request to an element](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing) – e.g. your Single entry – it'll automatically populate your template with an `entry` variable. In other words, if the current page is the actual URL for your Single entry, you won't need to do any `craft.entries` query at all (this is true for all Entries and Categories that have URLs enabled).